# How to check if the application has access to a Directory?

Tags: c#, .net

In my application I need to check whether or not I have permissions to write to a folder. I use the following method:

```
public bool IsAvailable(string path)
        {
            bool hasPermissions = false;

            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                var permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, path);
                try
                {
                    permission.Demand();
                    hasPermissions = true;
                }
                catch(SecurityException e)
                {
                    hasPermissions = false;
                }
            }

            return hasPermissions;
        }
```

When I give it a path to a Folder that I know for certain no one has access to it (I've removed all permission for all users in the Security Tab of the Folder Properties), it doesn't throw any exception. It just continues along the try block.

Any ideas why or how to do this check better?

The AppDomain.PermissionSet Property related answers I found on other question had no succes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Code Access Security constructs you're using are enforced at the level of the .NET runtime, and are higher level and completely independent of the security descriptors used for access control by the operating system. That said, the gist of phresnel's answer is correct - *any* check you perform is subject to being out of date by the time you get around to trying some I/O, so the better approach is just to try the I/O and be prepared for it to fail due to permissions problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had used the following method to get it done:

```
public static bool HasWritePermissionOnDir(string path)
    {
        var writeAllow = false;
        var writeDeny = false;
        var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
        if (accessControlList == null)
            return false;
        var accessRules = accessControlList.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
        if (accessRules == null)
            return false;

        foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
        {
            if ((FileSystemRights.Write & rule.FileSystemRights) != FileSystemRights.Write) continue;

            if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
                writeAllow = true;
            else if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                writeDeny = true;
        }

        return writeAllow && !writeDeny;
    }
```

Please let me know if it helped you and if yes mark it too

Comment: this worked... now to understand the code... I know that race conditions can occur, but this is the code that helps. thank you.

Comment: hello can you tell me how to do above code for list of path I mean passing list of path in argument instead of only one path.

Comment: @Neel : did you mean this : List<string> path

Comment: you can always write a program as public bool IsAvailable(List<string> path) and process all the paths with a foreach .. and I am not Anjali

Comment: I deny access to the folder for authenticated users with "s-1-5-11", but I got AccessContolType Allow and Deny for this certain SID. Does anyone know why? Why do I get Allow?

Answer (score 2):

This method (ask if accessible, then do something) is prone to race conditions. Between your check and an actual access to content in that directory, the permissions may change.

Better just try to read/write something in that directory, and catch a potential exception.

So don't

```
if(IsAvailable(path)) {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (...) {
    }
}
```

but rather

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (...) {
}
```

---

Grace Hopper quote:

> “It’s always easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission.”

Comment: or I could attempt to write temporary file into that folder and if that fails, return false, else return true and delete the temporary file...

Comment: Yeah, like you asked for it in "Any ideas why or how to do this check better?" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);    
var writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, filename);
permissionSet.AddPermission(writePermission);

if (permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet))
{}
```

Comment: Maybe you could make it a habit to provide explanations in your answers. This will also gain you more upvotes ;)