# How To Verify Network Folder Access

Tags: vb.net, directory, user-permissions

### Goal

To verify if a user has access to write / delete files on a specific network folder. For example:

`\\MyCompany\Department\DocumentCenter\` is the directory where all the files are stored for the document center program. If a user has access to this folder, he is able to add / edit / delete files. If not, an error is caught by my try-catch.

---

### Current Solution

I have attempted to solve this by setting up a try-catch right before the user deletes the file. If the user encounters an error, he will get a message saying that he does not have access... I find this rather trivial and would like a more concrete way of determining if the user has access to this folder.

---

How do I verify if a user has access to this specified folder?

Comment: Check this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842034/in-net-check-that-the-current-user-may-write-to-a-directory)

Comment: @fnostro The Method `IsGranted` is now obsolete. Anyway, for now my "solution" worked. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656058/how-to-check-if-the-application-has-access-to-a-directory

Answer (score 2):

When attempting to add / edit / delete a file on the given directory, as mentioned, I provide a try catch like so:

```vb
Private Sub DeleteFile(ByVal Path As String)
    Try
        'Example of Path: \\MyCompany\Department\DocumentCenter\File.PDF
        File.Delete(Path)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Cannot delete this file. Contact your system admnistrator to have access to this directory.")
    End Try
End Sub
```